# How do we get the result $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, vectors, inner-products

Let $x, p\neq q\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We have that $d(p,x)=d(q,x)$, so $\|p-x\|=\|q-x\|$, so  $(p-x)\cdot (p-x)=(q-x)\cdot (q-x)$.

I want to show that $$x-2\frac{(q-p)\cdot \left (x-\frac{1}{2}(p+q)\right )}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p)=x$$
We have that \begin{align*}x&-2\frac{(q-p)\cdot \left (x-\frac{1}{2}(p+q)\right )}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p)  \\ & =x-2\frac{(q-p)\cdot \left (\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}(p+q)\right )}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p)\\ & =x-2\frac{(q-p)\cdot \left (\frac{1}{2}(x-p)+\frac{1}{2}(x-q)\right )}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p)\\ & =x-2\frac{\frac{1}{2}(q-p)\cdot (x-p)+\frac{1}{2}(q-p)\cdot(x-q)}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p) \\ & =x-\frac{(q-p)\cdot (x-p)+(q-p)\cdot(x-q)}{(q-p)\cdot (q-p)}(q-p)\end{align*}
Is  that correct so far? How can we use the given property to get the result?

Comment: You can cancel $x$ from the equation, and then clear the fraction so that all you're actually trying to show is
$$(q-p)\cdot(x-\tfrac12(p+q))=0$$ (This *must* be true, since it's saying that the median from the vertex of an isosceles triangle is perpendicular to the base.) One way to proceed is to write the parts in terms of $x-p$ and $x-q$; you've done that with the second part, so all you need is a bit of cleverness with the first part.

Comment: I got it now!! Thank you very mich for your hint!! :-) @Blue